# Dynamically access const object literal in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types, eval

I'm working with a TypeScript library that generates TypeScript code, called [ts-proto](https://github.com/stephenh/ts-proto)

This generated code looks like this:

```
    //BasicMessage.ts

    export interface BasicMessage {
      id: Long;
      name: string;
    }

    export const BasicMessage = {
     encode(message: BasicMessage) : Writer {
        ...
     }

     fromJSON(object: any): BasicMessage {
        ...
     }
   }
```

and

```
   // BasicMessagePlus.ts
  
   export interface BasicMessagePlus {
      id: Long;
      name: string;
      email: string;
   }

   export const BasicMessagePlus = {
     encode(message: BasicMessagePlus) : Writer {
        ...
     }

     fromJSON(object: any): BasicMessagePlus {
        ...
     }
   }
```

Since this code is generated, I can't change it. What I need to do is create a method that takes a type name and an object and encodes it, something like this:

```
   function encode(typeName: string, object: any): Writer {
      import(`/path/to/${typeName}`);
      return <typeName>.encode(<typeName>.fromJSON(object));
   }

   let writer1 = encode("BasicMessage", { id: 1, name: "Fake" });
   let writer2 = encode("BasicMessagePlus", { id: 1, name: "Fake", email: "fake@fake.com" });
```

I've tried all type of tricks using eval and globalThis, but I just can't find a combination that lets me do what I'm trying to do. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic imports like this are pretty much impossible for typescript to reason about. What if this function gets passed `"ThisDoesNotExist"`?

So you have to import all the available items generated this way into one object that can be used to look them up.

```
import { BasicMessage } from './path/to/BasicMessage'
import { BasicMessagePlus } from './path/to/BasicMessagePlus'
const encodables = { BasicMessage, BasicMessagePlus }
```

Now you can constrain `typeName` to a `keyof` that object, and everything works:

```
function encode(
  typeName: keyof typeof encodables,
  data: any
): string {
  const encoder = encodables[typeName]
  return encoder.encode(encoder.fromJSON(data))
}
```

That third line is a mouthful. Basically, it gets the type of the argument of the encode method of the chosen encoder.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4&ssl=32&ssc=2&pln=26&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgIUwGcFsBZYIozAczwG8AoORAEwC44kBXAWwCM0AbmZdMvYJyIwoyGiIC+jRqEiw42CEmkFipClVp4AvHCYtgSTa2AAKCYbqdCJcpWp0AlGbhRgMbigkOAcPYAA6JHE8BQAaUXQoCF4AKQBlAHkAOVtWTBhMTkwkAE9vel9-QOC8grglJRVwaHhkVAwcPBd9dyMABQAbbiIzUQQOLj5BKBEWKIkpGTlZuGBeTAQBxdkkeUZG1RaNLR1ut0dgQeG4U3NVqwgbe16nXVcDMKuib225Hz8AkEQi8ImsNgN6vEWIlkulsrl8oU4MUyv8qkDaph6vtlAB6XEAWiJyk02nglmsmH4A0oNx8Zw+Rlibx6Fy+2MY6G4VhgCC092sdlEMBKYGAWWinAA1sAShB0HARWL5QLHlSaUQoXBMUVSoxPL9dqMWKSdBTHmg6ea8tTKABtJXi6IAXVEAOqqpsUHC1rsvu9MNSmRymM8nhxjBp8AA7rJ2gBGK0PJ4AIgZIJTzIq4048eZ80kcBTADFMDKU-VPCIo3BYwh2gAmJOC2xpvTnT5DIiZnw5uB5sQLIul8vMsGbTgprAygAC04iml4FYUVaAA)

---

Note that `data` here is of type `any`, mainly because that's how your `fromJSON` method is typed. If you want to enforce a certain type as the second argument according to which encoder was chosen, then this gets a lot more complicated.